# Angular: Get instance of a pipe class only by a given pipeName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I spend hours to find how i can get object instance of a pipe class only by the name of the pipe.

For example :

```
let uppercasePipeInstance: UpperCasePipe = getPipeByName(pipeName);
uppercasePipeInstance.transform('some params');
```

-----------> Is that possible in angular ??

-----------> How can I achieve this even if it was complicate to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

Construct your own object as `{ key: value}` pairs.
like

```
availablePipes = { uppercase: 'UpperCasePipe', lowercase: 'LowerCasePipe' };
```

Then:

```
private getPipeByName(pipeName: string) {
    const pipe = this.availablePipes.pipeName;
    if(pipe) {
        this[pipe]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can inject instances of pipes into the constructor. You will need to register it as a provider in your module or your component.

app.module.ts

```js
import { UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [ UpperCasePipe ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

component.ts

```js
constructor(private upperCasePipe: UpperCasePipe) {}

value: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.value = this.upperCasePipe.transform('some value');
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnx1za

I assume you are only using `UpperCasePipe` as a simple example, because obviously it would be redundant to inject that particular pipe instead of using javascript string functions.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I'm looking for getting a pipe in dynamic way only by providing a pipeName. I put uppercase pipe just for an example.

Comment: You statically typed it in your example: `let uppercasePipeInstance: UpperCasePipe = getPipeByName(pipeName);`. Shouldn't it look something more like this: `let pipeInstance: PipeTransform = getPipeByName(pipeName);` if you don't know the type at design time?

Comment: Thank you for your help but your solution doesn't allow to dynamically a pipe from a string with the name :(

Comment: @WaZaA can you provide a stackblitz to demonstrate your use case rather than just downvoting the answer?

Comment: Sorry @KurtHamilton, bad use of down vote on my part.
Your answer just does not answer the question - the problem is to get a pipe by is name, like with a string - but your proposition works.
I can't undo down vote since your answer is not edited.

Comment: @WaZaA On re-reading this answer I did realise that it doesn't actually answer the original question. There are often cases on SO where an answerer will suggest what they think is a better solution, even though it doesn't directly answer the question. This is sometimes good and sometimes bad. I would still be interested to know the use case that you and OP have, to help come up with a better solution.